# how to know What checkbox is checked when i press any button that in my form

Tags: android

i have in my android form 5 checkbox

how to know What checkbox is checked when i press any button that in my form

Comment: please try to do some research before  posting on [SO] start with http://developer.android.com examples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_id);
 if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
     //dostuff
 }
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html

Comment: thanks for the help, this happens when i check or uncheck the checkbox - and i need to know witch checkbox was checked when i press the button

Comment: you can also define a OnCheckedChangeListener -> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setOnCheckedChangeListener%28android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener%29

Answer (score 0):

Since findViewById does an expensive lookup perform all your findViewById assignments in onCreate function of your activity and assign it to a global variable. Later on your click events you can check each check box's status.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private Checkbox cbox1;
    private Checkbox cbox2;
    private Checkbox cbox3;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        cbox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);
        cbox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox2);
        cbox3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox3);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (cbox1.isChecked()) {
                    //checkbox 1 checked
                }
                //check other checkboxes..
            }
        });
    }
}
```